# Read XML columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, pivot

Trying to get the values and element names extracted from one XML column.

Values are getting just in one row and not able to extract the element name.

The elements in the cell are like this:
6161...
And they are dynamically generated.

Here is the code:

```
 SELECT mainSku, r.value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'value', r.query('.') AS 'secondarySku'
  FROM [productsMatrix] 
    CROSS APPLY details.nodes('/') AS x(r)
  WHERE mainSku = 'TP40106'
```

[This is the wrong actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXqfz.png)

[This is the result that is pretended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvdi7.png)

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the XML column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is far away from being clear, but my magic crystall ball is showing, that you might be looking for this:

```
SELECT mainSku
      ,r.value('text()[1]','int') AS [value]
      ,r.value('local-name(.)') AS [secondarySku]
FROM [productsMatrix]
CROSS APPLY details.nodes('/*') AS x(r)
WHERE mainSku = 'TP40106'
```

### Assumptions:

Your table `[productsMatrix]` has got an XML column called `details`. This column contains an XML **with no root node**, just a list of XML-Elements with names like `<AC486>`.

The `CROSS APPLY` on `.nodes()` will return a list of all first-level-nodes, while the query picks the content (`text()`-node) and the element's name.

Comment: My crystal ball suffers from cataracts.

Comment: Shnugo you're a true SQL wizard! It worked :) Thank you so much!